# How to compress a list

Tags: ocaml

I have a list: `["a"; "a"; "a"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "x"; "e"; "e"; "e"]` which I want to compress. In other words, remove duplicates on left and right side of each index.

The function `compress l` should return `["a"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "a"; "d"; "x"; "e"]`

I've already tried this function in OCaml:

```ml
let compress list = 
  List.filteri 
    (fun i el -> compare (List.nth list i) el != 0) 
    list;;
```

*But* it throws me the error **Exception: Failure "nth".**

Comment: No it doesn't. What you've written is effectively a no-op, it just checks that every element in the list is the same as itself, in an incredibly inefficient way. I can imagine what you did to get that exception though, and my advice would be to not use `List.nth`. It's a dead-end. So is using `List.filter`. Instead you should write your own recursive function to look at two elements of the list at a time.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `"c"` in your example:  ["a"; "c"; "b"; ***"c";*** "a"; "d"; "x"; "e"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `List.fold_right` to build a new list by only adding unique elements:

```ml
let add_if_unique x = function
  | [] -> [x]
  | y :: r -> if x = y then y::r else x::y::r
  ;;
val add_if_unique : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>

let compress l = List.fold_right add_if_unique l [];;
val compress : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>

compress ["a"; "a"; "a"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "x"; "e"; "e"; "e"];;
- : string list = ["a"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "a"; "d"; "x"; "e"]
```

Note that List.fold_left is often preferable to List.fold_right in Ocaml. In this case it would build the list in reverse, so we need to combine it with List.rev:

```ml
let add_if_unique l x = match l with
  | [] -> [x]
  | y :: _ -> if x = y then l else x::l
  ;;
val add_if_unique : 'a list -> 'a -> 'a list = <fun>

let compress l = List.rev (List.fold_left add_if_unique [] l);;
val compress : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>

compress ["a"; "a"; "a"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "c"; "a"; "a"; "d"; "x"; "e"; "e"; "e"];;
- : string list = ["a"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "a"; "d"; "x"; "e"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Since we're already in the why-do-your-own-homework-when-people-on-SO-will-happily-do-it-for-you-phase of this question, I think a hand-written recursive function is significantly simpler and easier to understand than a fold:

```
let rec compress = function
  | a :: b :: rest when a = b -> compress (a :: rest)
  | a :: rest -> a :: (compress rest)
  | [] -> []
```

It's not tail recursive, but that's easy to fix and left as an exercise for the reader. For the purpose of understanding the algorithm it will just distract.

Comment: I agree it's likely that the question is the OP's homework but I'm not sure what the sarcastic remark is aiding.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci It tells others answering questions here to think about whether they're actually helping anyone by blurting out answers to obvious homework questions, especially the "clever" non-pedagogical kind of answers that serve mostly to boost their own ego. And to some extent it tells OP to make more of an effort themselves. This could of course haven been explained without sarcasm, but that would have made the tangent longer and the impact lower. Sarcasm is a tool to make the message "stick" better (but can also have other bad side-effects and loses its effectiveness if overused.)

Comment: It also helps to explain why I'm giving a straight-up answer myself despite also saying that doing so is generally bad.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, if you do want to use `List.nth`, which [glennsl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7943564/glennsl) is right in [telling you not to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75841789/how-to-compress-a-list#comment133778484_75841789) in this case, you could create a recursive function which starts at one index and counts forward until it finds an item which doesn't match.

```ml
let rec next_index_diff i lst =
  let x = List.nth lst i in
  let rec aux i lst =
    if List.nth lst i <> x then i
    else aux (i+1) lst
  in
  aux (i+1) lst
```

```
# let lst = ["a"; "a"; "a"; "c"; "b"; "c"; "c"; 
             "a"; "a"; "d"; "x"; "e"; "e"; "e"] in
  (next_index_diff 0 lst, next_index_diff 10 lst);;
- : int * int = (3, 11)
```

Now, we can use this tool to implement a compress function by using the result of `next_index_diff` to skip ahead to the next index with a different value than the current one. That function will raise `Failure` if the current element is the last unique one. We can handle that by returning a list with that single element.

```
let compress lst =
  let rec aux i lst =
    let x = List.nth lst i in
    try
      let n = next_index_diff i lst in
      x :: aux n lst
    with
    | Failure _ -> [x]
  in
  aux 0 lst
```

As `List.nth` must iterate from the beginning of the list each time, this is an inefficient approach to solving this problem, and this answer is provided simply for demonstration.

It may help to see how `List.nth` [is implemented](https://github.com/lucasaiu/ocaml/blob/master/stdlib/list.ml) to understand this:

> ```
> let nth l n =
>   if n < 0 then invalid_arg "List.nth" else
>   let rec nth_aux l n =
>     match l with
>     | [] -> failwith "nth"
>     | a::l -> if n = 0 then a else nth_aux l (n-1)
>   in nth_aux l n
> ```